# How to merge multiple powerpoint files in a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powerpoint, merge

I have a document library in a SharePoint 2016 site, there are several Powerpoint files (pptx files) in this library. I want to add a button to the web page so when users click that button, these pptx files will be merged into one pptx file. 
The issue is I can't use Sharepoint designer to do much development, or can't do much on the server due to firm policy. Only thing I can do is to write some JavaScript web parts.

Can anyone give me a suggestion in my case?

also, I see in SharePoint 2010 version there's a Slide library, it can merge pptx files. Can I write some lines of JavaScript to call functions used in the Slide library in 2016 version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Slide Library was used to store individual slides. PowerPoint 2007-2013 had the ability to work with that library to let users select a slide from the library and insert it into their open PowerPoint file. I think this feature has been removed from Office 2016/Office 365. I don't know of any way from JavaScript to build a new PowerPoint presentation from slides in a Slide Library.

See the comments at the end of this article for more info on which versions work: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/11/finding-missing-sharepoint-2013-slide.html

Microsoft has recommendations for an alternate solution for sharing slides here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/work-together-on-powerpoint-presentations-0c30ee3f-8674-4f0e-97be-89cf2892a34d